# Repeat array x times, then repeat again removing first item until array disappears

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-sheets

**What I want**:

I am writing a function for Google Sheets. This is what I want it to do. It's based on Javascript.

1. Feed the formula an array (actually given to the function as a range of cells in a Google Sheet) and a number
2. The function repeats the array in full the number of times equal to the second number ('amount').
3. The function then repeats, removing the first (or last, whichever is easier) item in the array, until there are no more entries in the array to spit out.

For example, if I give it the array `[a,b,c,d,e]` and the number 2, it would give me:

a
b
c
d
e
a
b
c
d
e
b
c
d
e
c
d
e
d
e
e

Repeating the full length twice, then the array-1 until there is nothing left in the array.

**What it does**:

Currently, it repeats the array equal to the length of the array. So for [a,b,c] it gives me:

a
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
c

**Current code**:

```
function stack(range,amount) {
var stack = []; 
for(var i=0; i<range.length; i++)
//^ Count through Amount
 {
  for(var j=0, jLen=range.length; j<jLen; j++)
  //^ While j is less than the length of the range...
   {
    stack.push(range[j]);
    p++;
    //^ Add the current index j of the range to the array
  }
 }    
return stack;
//^ Spit out the array stack
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be clearest to use two loops, one to do the full copies `amount` times, then a second loop to do the progressively shorter copies.

```js
function stack(range, amount) {
  var i, j;
  var result = [];
  
  for (i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < range.length; j++) {
      result.push(range[j]);
    }
  }
  
  for (i = 1; i < range.length; i++) {
    for (j = i; j < range.length; j++) {
      result.push(range[j]);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(stack(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 2).join(" "));
```

You can make this shorter by replacing the inner loops with a combination of `.slice()` and `.push.apply()`:

```js
function stack(range, amount) {
  var i;
  var result = [];
  var push = Array.prototype.push;
  
  for (i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    push.apply(result, range.slice());
  
  for (i = 1; i < range.length; i++)
    push.apply(result, range.slice(i));
               
  return result;
}

console.log(stack(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 2).join(" "));
```

Further reading:

- [Array `.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [Function `.apply()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Wow I didn't expect such a concise answer so quickly! This really puts me ahead, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
function stack(range, amount) {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) arr.push(...range);

    const temp = range.slice();
    while (temp.length){
        temp.shift();
        arr.push(...temp);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: The `...` operator really does help tidy up the code, doesn't it? Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do as follows with a single liner, `Array.prototype.reduce()` instruction.

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    res = arr.reduce((r,_,i,a) => r.concat(a.slice(i)),arr);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```